# Recorrer coleccion en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta consulta en laravel en el metodo store.

```
    $idRiesgo1            = $request->input('idRiesgo');
    $idOpcionTratamiento1 = $request->input('idOpcionTratamiento');

    $idControlL1 = DB::table('controles')->distinct()
                         ->select('controles.idControlL')
                         ->where([['controles.idRiesgo',            '=', $idRiesgo1],
                                  ['controles.idOpcionTratamiento', '=', $idOpcionTratamiento1]
                                ])
                         ->get();
```

lo cual haciendo dd, me muestra los datos de la coleccion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener cada uno de los elementos llamado idControlL, y lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera.

```
   foreach ($idControlL1 as  $idControlLs) {
       dd($idControlLs->idControlL);
   }
```

pero el dd me arroja solo un dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como podria recuperar todos los datos?.

Comment: desde el inicio del codigo hasta el final no existe ningun error, no se entiende lo que deseas. Si necesitas mas datos agregalos a tu `select('controles.idControlL')` o si quieres "todos los datos" tan solo borra ese `select`

Comment: creo que redacte mal la pregunta,mira lo que yo quiero ese solo obtener los valores del idControlL como se ve en la primera imagen, hay dos valores que son A.5.1.1 Y A.5.1.2, esos valores son los que quiero obtener pero separados por cada iteraccion, pero como puedes ver el foreach solo me retorna uno que es A.5.1.1

Comment: aun sigo sin entender quizas solo buscas ver todos los resultados, dd solo muestra el dato que se le pasa y despues hace una pausa-stop del foreach. Quizas quieras ver los datos con `dump`, Cambia el `dd` por `dump`

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias.

Comment: Seriaa bueno que pongas la solucion que encontraste, para que otros que se encuentren con el mismo problema tengan una solucion aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Al ser una colección de Laravel puedes hacer un pluck.

`$idControlL1->pluck('idControlL')`

Te devolverá un array con todos los valores de idControlL

Answer (score 0):

El código está bien, las colecciones pueden ser iteradas mediante un `foreach`. El problema se debe a que estás utilizando `dd()` que es el equivalente a hacer un [dump](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) y un [die](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.die.php) (De ahí el nombre dd).

En otras palabras estás deteniendo el código en la primera iteración, por ende, solo muestra el primer valor.

Si quieres visualizar todos los valores de la colección de la forma en que lo hace `dd()` dentro del respectivo ciclo iterativo puedes utilizar `dump()`, que a diferencia de `dd()` no tiene el `die;` y no finalizará la ejecución del código.

Puedes leer más sobre [dump](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump) y [dd](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) en los respectivos enlaces. Si quieres debuggear sin detener la ejecución del código te recomiendo utilizar los [logs de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) o el paquete [laravel dump server](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server) que funcionará de manera similar a los logs.